# Python Tkinter Use Entry Field to Create MessageBox

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm somewhat new to Tkinter with minor Python experience so I hope the answer's not too obvious, I've attempted to search for an answer but couldn’t find anything helpful. Essentially I'm trying to build a program where (as a placeholder test for now), if a user enters 1 in the entry field and hits submit, a window appears telling them they typed 1, otherwise they're told to type 1. If my understandings correct, this should work:

```
    from Tkinter import *
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    import tkMessageBox
    root = Tk()
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    root.title('Payroll System')
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    def on_printtext(root):
        global entryform
        string = entryform.get()
        if string == 1:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('You typed 1')
        elif string != 1:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo('Please type 1')
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    entryform = Entry(root)
    entryform.pack()
    submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=on_printtext)
    submit.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

However when I try to run it and enter 1 in the entry form after hitting submit I get this:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in call
        return self.func(*args)
    TypeError: on_printtext() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that tkinter is trying to call the function registered as the `command` for the button without any arguments, but your function has 1 argument - `root` without any default variable, and hence that is causing the issue you are having.

Also some other issues in your code -

1. `Entry.get()` returns a string, but you are trying to compare that against an integer , it would never be equal, so even if you enter 1 it would still show `Please type 1` .
2. When you do - `tkMessageBox.showinfo('You typed 1')` - you are actually setting the `title` to `You typed 1` , not the actual message. For the functions of tkMessageBox`, the first argument is the title, and the second argument is the message. If you want that as the message, set it as the`message` using keyword argument. Example -

   ```
   tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='You typed 1')
   ```

Example code that works -

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
root.title('Payroll System')
def on_printtext():
    global entryform
    strng = entryform.get()
    if strng == '1':
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='You typed 1')
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(message='Please type 1')

entryform = Entry(root)
entryform.pack()
submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=on_printtext)
submit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.x, the code above does not work since tkMessageBox has been changed to messagebox.

Here's the modified code:

```
from tkinter import * # modif 1 Tkinter with minus t !
import tkinter.messagebox # modif 2:tkMessageBox no longer valid

root = Tk()
root.title('Payroll System')
def on_printtext():
    global entryform
    strng = entryform.get()
    if strng == '1':
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='You typed 1') # modif 3
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message='Please type 1') # modif 4

entryform = Entry(root)
entryform.pack()
submit = Button(root, text="Submit", command=on_printtext)
submit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```